# Kanji for みない　in 調べてみない

Tags: kanji

> 詳｛くわ｝しく調｛しら｝べて**みない**と分｛わ｝かんないって

In the sentence above, what is the kanji for みない?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case of ～てみる, the みる is classified as an auxiliary verb ([補助動詞]{ほ・じょ・どう・し}).  Auxiliary verbs are "always" written in hiragana.  I suppose if you *had* to use kanji, then 見る is the most generic of all the possibilities.

See also [Use of kanji when writing 言う](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/59258/78).

Comment: デジタル大辞泉 says てみる→見る12